# Spring security login/logout url related issue

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security

I am using spring security for my application. Following are some lines from my applicationContext-Security.xml to set access as ROLE_USER for /offers and /add links and no filters for /list link.

```
<intercept-url pattern="/list*" filters="none" />
<intercept-url pattern="/offers**" access="ROLE_USER" />
<intercept-url pattern="/add/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
```

I want to show **LOGIN** link when user is not logged in and when user logs in to system then this link should be replaced by **LOGOUT**.
For that I tried following code in my jsp page.

```
<security:authorize ifNotGranted="ROLE_USER">  
  <a href="login.jsp">Login</a>
</security:authorize>

<security:authorize ifAnyGranted="ROLE_USER">
  Welcome <security:authentication property="principal.username"/>! &nbsp; 
| <a href="logout.htm">Logout</a>     
</security:authorize>
```

When I am on /list link, It shows "LOGIN" link.
After login if user redirected to /offers or /add link then it shows "Welcome UserName | LOGOUT" which is working as per requrment. But Problem is, when user logs in and redirected to /list page then also it shows "LOGIN"*(USER is already logged in)* It should show  "Welcome UserName | LOGOUT"

Help me in this scenario, What should I do to get it working?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Which version of spring-security?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution, may be useful for others who are looking for same question.
Remove line below from security XML file.

```
<intercept-url pattern="/list*" filters="none" />
```

And code will work. It is because, when you specify filters="none" to certain link, then your context do not return granted authority to your jsp page. So when we redirect to list page after logging in, authorize tag says that its not authorized as ROLE_USER and execute following lines,

```
<security:authorize ifNotGranted="ROLE_USER">  
  <a href="login.jsp">Login</a>
</security:authorize>
```

So just remove filter from that link.

Comment: Yes, by setting filters="none" yo remove all the Spring Security filters from the chain when this url is proccessed, so the User logged is not available. If you want to allow the url to all the users use <sec:intercept-url pattern="/list*" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY, IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED" /> instead.