# Spring Security Authorize tag always false

Tags: spring-security

I have about the equivalent to the following in my jsp.  Neither here nor there are displayed!

My first foray into Spring Security 3.0.5.  I've used 3.0.3 without issue.

```
<sec:authorize ifNotGranted="ROLE_ACTIVE">
    here
</sec:authorize>
<sec:authorize ifAnyGranted="ROLE_ACTIVE">
    there       
</sec:authorize>
```

Comment: I should add no errors or warnings anywhere.  Rest of the page renders fine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks for the insights.  I found it was because of the ordering of the filter-mappings.  Spring security needs to come before Sitemesh.

Not sure how anyone could have gotten that without me publishing so many seemingly trivial details on the project.

I'll know to post the web.xml in the future.  Probably just pay more attention to that being a source of problems.

Comment: In working with Spring Security, sometimes things just...happen because of built-in functionality.  For example, I had things set up correctly, but all of my authorization checks were returning false.  Why?  I needed to debug, so I downloaded the source JARs from Jarvana and stepped through the source.Turns out the roles needed to be prefixed with `ROLE_`.In this case, having to have Spring Security filter before Sitemesh sounds fishy - one doesn't seem to have that much to do with the other.  Have you stepped through the code to see what is causing the behavior under the hood?

Comment: This fixed it for me, moved Spring Security's `DelegatingFilterProxy` above `SiteMeshFilter` in my web.xml

Answer (score 1):

Looks like ifNotGranted and ifAnyGranted are deprecated in favor of the access expression.  Try something like

```
<sec:authorize access="hasRole('ROLE_ACTIVE')">here</sec:authorize>
```

Comment: Just tried it still no go.  Nice to know they are deprecated though will use access I guess.

Comment: The next question would then be if your principal is setup correctly (.i.e. has the role you think they do) and if your tags are being evaluated.  If you view source, you don't have <sec:authorize in the text, right?  Finally, you could try access="permitAll" and see if it your "here" value.

Comment: permitAll still will not render the content.  I know they have the role properly because it does secure and allow access to the SpringMVC @RequestMapping with @Secured for the given role as well.  The controller security seems to work great.

Answer (score 1):

If you setted filters='none' for the jsp page and writing above code on the same jsp then your authorize tag will always return false.

you can refer this question, your problem may be same I belive.

[Spring security login/logout url related issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4896289/spring-security-login-logout-url-related-issue)

If your problem is different then can you elaborate more on your security configuration.

Comment: This was exactly my problem I had: security="none" for my url. So I changed it to access="permitAll"